# Django model class inheritance - default fields and overrides

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance

I'm attempting to have inherited class templates, so that all my models have certain default fields, and all have default overrides for a few functions like save_model()

If I do it like this, I get the overrides, but then have to go and manually set meta data like db_table...

```
class ModelExtension(models.Model):
    altered_by = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class SomeModel(ModelExtension):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_somemodel'
    fields = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Is there a way to get this kind of inheritance working right?  So far I either have to do extra work to compensate for the drawbacks of this approach, or I'm plagued by MRO errors.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's an MRO error? Have you read the django docs on model inheritance? You can either have Abstract Base Classes, Multi-table inheritance, or proxy models.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

What you've done there is a multi-table inheritance - there's a hidden OneToOneField connecting your two models. I don't know why you think you need the db_table specified - it shouldn't be.

If you are never going to have objects of bare class ModelExtension then you want abstract base classes. In this case you put abstract=True in the Meta section, and then all the fields from the base class are added to the table for the child class. The docs explain it better than I can here.

I often find myself starting to do it one way and then flipping back and forth several times as I think more about my database structure....

Comment: If I don't specify db_table, ALL inherited models have a db_table of 'app_modelextension'

Comment: Weird, I thought without abstract=True each model should have an app_modelextension _and_ an app_somemodel table with that extra OneToOne field linking them. That's what the docs imply!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add new *functionality* to a model without changing its fields, use a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)!

Comment: I want functionality AND fields.